# I'm unable to delete an existing localstorage value in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-local-storage

As a personal project, I'm working on a food calculator in backbone.js. I'm storing the food entries via backbone.localstorage.js.  I've got most of it working fine.  The only issue that I'm having is after I save my items and I hit refresh, I'm unable to delete the items.  If I add an item, I can delete it directly after I delete it.

Here's my function where I initialize everything:

```
initialize: function () {        
        this.model = new SearchList();
        this.foods = new AllFoods();
        this.journal = new FoodJournalDay();
        this.prepCollection = _.debounce(this.prepCollection, 1000);
        this.$totalcal = $('#totalcal span');
        this.$totalcalfat = $('#totalcalfat span');
        this.$totalprotein = $('#totalprotein span');
        this.$totalcarb = $('#totalcarb span');
        this.$totalfat = $('#totalfat span');
        this.$totalsugar = $('#totalsugar span');
        this.$totalsodium = $('#totalsodium span');
        this.$totalpotassium = $('#totalpotassium span');
        this.$list = $('#listing');
        this.$breakfast = $('#breakfast');
        this.$lunch = $('#lunch');
        this.$dinner = $('#dinner');
        this.$snack = $('#snack');
        this.$tracked = $('#tracked');

        this.listenTo(this.journal, 'all', _.debounce(this.render, 0));
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
        this.listenTo(this.journal, 'destroy', this.renderfoods);        
        this.foods.fetch();        

        var myNotes = new FoodJournalDay();
        myNotes.fetch();

        myNotes.models.forEach(function(model){

            var mealli = model.get("html");

            var calcount = parseFloat(model.get("calories"));
            var proteincount = parseFloat(model.get("protein"));
            var carbscount = parseFloat(model.get("carbs"));
            var fatcount = parseFloat(model.get("fat"));
            var sugarcount = parseFloat(model.get("sugar"));

            totalcal += calcount;
            totalprotein += proteincount;
            totalcarb += carbscount;
            totalfat += fatcount;
            totalsugar += sugarcount;

            switch (model.get("meal")) {

                case 'Breakfast':
                    $('#breakfast').append(mealli);
                    break;
                case 'Lunch':
                        $('#lunch').append(mealli);
                    break;
                case 'Dinner':
                        $('#dinner').append(mealli);
                    break;
                case 'Snack':
                    $('#snack').append(mealli);
                    break;
                default:
                    //alert("Please select a meal!");
            }


            $('#totalcal span').html(totalcal);
            $('#totalprotein span').html(totalprotein);
            $('#totalcarb span').html(totalcarb);
            $('#totalfat span').html(totalfat);
            $('#totalsugar span').html(totalsugar);
        });
    },
```

Here is my delete function:

```
destroy: function (e) {
        var $li = $(e.currentTarget).closest('li');
        var id = $li.attr('data-id');
        $li.remove();

        console.log("li id: " + id);
        console.log(this.journal);

        this.journal.get(id).destroy();
    },
```

I've made a fiddle of what I'm working on:
https://jsfiddle.net/brettdavis4/ynm2sse9/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm back for round 2 :p.

You added 2 identical collections to the view. You should stick with one.

Originally you had `this.journal = new FoodJournalDay();` as your collection. And in my previous answer `this.journal.get(id).destroy();` successfully deleted the item. However in your new code you've created another collection `var myNotes = new FoodJournalDay();`. This is fairly pointless because you already have a `FoodJournalDay()` collection assigned to `this.journal`.

You populated `myNotes` with a `fetch()`, thus you left `this.journal` empty. Since `this.journal` is doing the deletion, it tries to find the model with the id `this.journal.get(id)`. This returns `undefined` since there is no model with that `id`, in fact there are no models at all in the collection. That's why you get the error msg `Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined`.

When something isn't working, i suggest following the flow of the program and placing `console.log()` statements everywhere checking the contents of your collection, models, and see if you can pick up any unexpected behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/1mq7mdm1/

I replaced

```
var myNotes = new FoodJournalDay();
myNotes.fetch();

myNotes.models.forEach(function(model){
```

with this. Using the original collection.

```
this.journal.fetch();
this.journal.models.forEach(function(model){
```